# Is there any way to read an technical ebook quickly?

Tags: ebook-readers

I am reading a technical computing science ebook. I want to know if is there any software or way so that I read only the relevant content only( which is important) ?

Comment: Please add some explanation. What do you mean by "the relevant content only?" What makes the content relevant or irrelevant? As it is, this question is unclear and may be closed.

Comment: If the question is about speed reading, it is OFF TOPIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a bunch of techniques.
short time ago i found a new one, called spritz.
http://youtu.be/slYKEKtYW-I

Other techniques are: speedreading, photoreading etc.